# Install api "mobile vision" from play store

Tags: android, ocr

I try the samples about OCR. But samples don't implement "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision" auto installation on debugged smartphone target.
I want to install the API from the Play-Store, but I don't know the "public" name of this application/API. I try with "Mobile vision", or "OCR", but nothing is corresponding to the good one. 
The doc. is on "https://developers.google.com/vision/android/getting-started"
[Mobile Vision logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkbZ9.png)
Some help ?

Comment: What do you mean by auto installation? To use vision api you only have to insert compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.2' in your gradle

Comment: With sample of "android-vision-master", application crashes immediatly when calling new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build(); I have the compile script line, but this doesn't garantee that the api is installed on target smartphone. This is only used for APK generation.

Comment: On some sample logs, I have a line as "W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found." This means that com.google.android.gms.vision is not installed on target. How ca I do that manualy with play store ?

Comment: Probably you haven't Google Play Services installed on your device. Is it a rooted device?

Comment: It is a standard Huawei Honor 8, with any specific customization. How do you install 'Google Play service' on the smartphone or Mr anybody in order to use OCR application ?

Comment: ok, I understand. In french it is "Services Google Play" : for me, release 11.7.46 (448-175121617). Is it ok ?

Comment: Yeah I think so, any progress by installing it?

Comment: Hello. Problem is known from android-vision team : bug on Smasung and Honor smartphone. See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/269

Comment: That's unfortunate, best wishes :)